# Where is the ExecuteMterpImpl function in aosp 13?

Tags: android, android-source

In aosp 11, there are two mode to execute java function in art.
In the interpreter mode, the execution always passes through ExecuteSwitchImplCpp, whereas in the assembly mode, it always passes through ExecuteMterpImpl.

But I can not find ExecuteMterpImpl in aosp android 13.
How does Android 13 handle the assembly mode?